# Changing styles on navigation links - including next and prev buttons

Tags: javascript, css, navigation

I'm currently working on a website for a Danish company. The content is all in one page and I've included some jQuery-scrolling and stuff. Works nice!

For the menu I'm asked to programme the elements so the active element is bold. That I've done too.

The problem comes here:
The client wants a home button and a next and previous button. But when I click them and the page scrolls the CSS-classes do not change for the active element - so the bold element in the menu is still the last clicked page.

I hope that anyone can help.

The page can be seen at:
http://vedelform.dk/new/intro/

Comment: Can you show the relevant jQuery code for where you are binding event handlers to the scrolling arrows?

Comment: @Russ: the code is here: http://www.vedelform.dk/new/wp-content/themes/vedelform/js/init.js  The event handlers are bound deep inside the SerialScroll plugin.

Comment: @crescentfresh - I started looking through the code and thought it may be easier for all to ask for where they're bound :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to calling the serialscroll plugin, the event handler for the images needs to update the appropriate class name on your navigation link. When you click on a navigation link directly, you call the changeActiveStates function, but that isn't happening with the home, next, and previous buttons.

You should use the onBefore attribute of the serialScroll plugin to define a method that will figure out which navigation link is supposed to receive the class name. It can then call the changeActiveStates function.

It doesn't look like it would take more than a few more lines of code to fix your problem. If you need more help getting it to work, let me know.

---

edit:

If you add this (starting at line 84 of init.js), you should be in business:

```
easing: 'swing',
onBefore:function(e, elem, $pane, $items, pos){
    if ((pos >= 0)&&(pos < $('ul.navigation > li > a').size())) changeActiveStates($('ul.navigation > li > a').get(pos));
    return true;
}
```

You will then need to call changeActiveStates (probably after you initialize the function) on page load to initialize the correct menu item.

I hope that helps; let me know if it gives you any more trouble.

Comment: would you care to help with my script?

Comment: Sure, I'll look at it again tonight.

Answer (score 0):

You used minified version of scripts so it is very hard to debug the code. Also you didnt give us name of plugin you use. I think there is a bug in plugin. Because css class "selected" sould jump from one menu item to another.

Comment: The plugin is serialScroll: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2008/02/jqueryserialscroll.html

Answer (score 0):

@Jason Francis:
You're probably right. I'm not that much into jQuery and Javascript and what I've done so far is more luck than it's knowledge. I did A LOT of trial and error.
I understand what you're saying about getting the serialScroll plugin to figure out what element to call changeActiveStates on - but I seriously don't know how to do that.